# R, caret: what does returnResamp mean in trainControl?

Tags: r, r-caret

In R, `caret` package: What does `returnResamp` mean in `trainControl`?

From the help information, 
`returnResamp` is a character string indicating how much of the resampled summary metrics should be saved. Values can be "final", "all" or "none". But really, what does it mean?

I could understand (or guess) what is `savePredictions`, which is how to save predicted value. Namely, three options, "none" = don't save, "final" use `indexFinal` to predict, "all" use all data points to predict. But what is `returnResamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`returnResamp` returns information on the resamples

It has three possible values as you mentioned:

none - do not so any info
final - show the info of the final resampling
all  - show info about all resamples

You can see an example here:

[Caret package for R. Which samples are held out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964502/caret-package-for-r-which-samples-are-held-out)

Comment: So seems this parameter doesn't influence the speed of training.